# Combining multiple Django Views/Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a website. On the Homepage, I want to show the posts in the center and show famous tags on the right side of the page. Now, posts and tags are two different apps and their views/tempaltes are calculated/generated in two separate functions.

How can I show what I want on my Homepage keeping my mind that its two different views being called. As far as I understand, I can only call a single view to show my homepage.

This must be possible but I am unable to understand this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as my understanding to this point, I will be required to call the post view, and fetch the tags from some tags class function and then pass both of them to the homepage template. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create a custom template tag that in this case called: [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into writing a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for the tags. That way the tag logic can stay in the right application.

Comment: you are correct, i think i need to go with the inclusion tags here as suggested by anhtran above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how these different apps render the templates. If they just render the template without extending from a base template you could simply use AJAX to load all the content into your homepage.

If not, then there is no other way than writing a custom solution for this. This could be an extension to your views, a custom template tag as already mentioned or something else according to what exactly you need.

Comment: i think i will need inclusion tags here as suggested by anhtran.